# Mapping curl_multi value with appropriate value of an array

Tags: php, curl-multi

I have an array like this:-

```
$venueLocations = array(
                         [0] => array(
                                      'id' => '3Bheip34nbh503k3k30',
                                      'latitude' => '22.45',
                                      'longitude' => '88.45'
                                ),
                         [1] => array(
                                      'id' => '3Bheip34nbherf456gh3k3k30',
                                      'latitude' => '22.455',
                                      'longitude' => '88.457'
                                ),
                         [2] => array(
                                      'id' => '3fcD34Gp3nbherf56gh3k3k30',
                                      'latitude' => '22.455',
                                      'longitude' => '88.457'
                                )
                  );
```

I want to hit Uber API using curl to get the estimated time to travel to the place.

I am using multi_curl_exec to run the curls simultaneously, rather than one after another. here is my code:-

```
public function simultaneousUberTimeEstimateCall($location, $venueLocation){
    $teList     = array();
    $placeList  = array();
    $multiCurl  = array();
    $result     = array();

    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $headers = array(
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                );

    foreach ($venueLocation as $i => $vloc) 
    {
        $url = self::$uberApiTimeEstimate .'?start_latitude=' . $location['latitude'] . '&start_longitude=' . $location['longitude'] . '&end_latitude=' . $vloc['latitude'] . '&end_longitude=' . $vloc['longitude'];
        $multiCurl[$i] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $venueDetailApiUrl);
        curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $multiCurl[$i]);
    }
    $index = null;
    do 
    {
        curl_multi_exec($mh,$index);
    } while($index > 0);

    // get content and remove handles
    foreach($multiCurl as $k => $ch) 
    {
        $result[$k] = json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($ch), TRUE);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
    }
    // close
    curl_multi_close($mh);

    foreach($result as $key => $estimatedTime)
    {
        if(!empty($estimatedTime['times'][0]['estimate']))
        {
            $te['uber_eta'] =  intval($estimatedTime['times'][0]['estimate'])/60;
        }
        else
        {
            $te['uber_eta'] = 'N/A'
        }
        $teList[] = $te;
    }
    return $teList;
}
```

The problem lies here:-

```
    foreach($result as $key => $estimatedTime)
    {
        if(!empty($estimatedTime['times'][0]['estimate']))
        {
            $te['uber_eta'] =  intval($estimatedTime['times'][0]['estimate'])/60;
        }
        else
        {
            $te['uber_eta'] = 'N/A'
        }
        $teList[] = $te;
    }
```

I want the $teList to be like this:-

```
$teList = array(
                         [0] => array(
                                      'id' => '3Bheip34nbh503k3k30',
                                      'uber_eta' => '8'
                                ),
                         [1] => array(
                                      'id' => '3Bheip34nbherf456gh3k3k30',
                                      'uber_eta' => '9'
                                ),
                         [2] => array(
                                      'id' => '3fcD34Gp3nbherf56gh3k3k30',
                                      'uber_eta' => '3'
                                )
                  );
```

How how to distinguish which curl values corresponds to which id? Is there any way by which I can send extra param to curl, and distinguish that a particular response data is associative with particular value of extra param?

Comment: Do you get id's back in the curl response

Comment: @Joseph_J, No, the curl response doesn't send back the IDs

Comment: @Joseph_J Do you mean that perhaps you curl 3 URLs but the fetched results are not in order and thus you 're confused how to sort them in order?

Comment: I mean that that he assigns the curl handles according to the index of the first array.  As the each handle closes it should preserve the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your keys from the $venueLocation should be the same order as you assigned the curl handles.  Therefore I'm pretty sure that the key order will be preserved for the responses.  So just add the id's from the $venueLocation array into the results array by key.

Try this:

```
foreach($result as $key => $estimatedTime){

  if(!empty($estimatedTime['times'][0]['estimate'])){

  $te['uber_eta'] =  intval($estimatedTime['times'][0]['estimate'])/60;

  }else{

    $te['uber_eta'] = 'N/A';

    }

  $teList[$key]['uber_eta'] = $te['uber_eta'];
  $teList[$key]['id']  = $venueLocation[$key]['id'];

}
```

Comment: I am reviewing the code man. Seems ok to me. I am just testing it.